# How to rotate part of an element

Tags: css, rotation

I know how to rotate an element (in 3D) in css but I was wondering whether it's possible to rotate part of an element? I would like to "chop" to element into say 5 pieces and rotate them in 3D simultanouesly.

The effect I'm looking for can be seen here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O9PvoV2jlco

But it's wokring since the rotated chopped elements are (from both sides) are images.

For example, assuming I would like to rotate two images on hover, and both of the images are divided into 5 pieces, HTML would be:

```
 <div className="container1">
       <div className="part p01">
               <img className="f1" src='cover.png')} alt=""/>
               <img className="f2" src='cover2.jpg')} alt=""/>
      </div>
</div>
```

And css would be:

```
.container1 {
  width: 720px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.part {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  transition: all .5s ease-in;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top:0px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.f1 {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.f2 {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

This would be 1/5 of the effect, flipping over 1/5 of the image on top to show the image on back on hovering.
But again, it's working only because these are images.

Of course, it's possible to just lay the complete element behind the flipping image but the effect won't be as nice.

If I would like the back of the card to be an element with 100% width, what could I do?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I made an edit moving the question right to the end of the body.  If it’s not to your taste feel free to revert.   I was a bit confused on my first read through.